# Map ctrl to leader key

Tags: vim

After seeing how doom-Emacs use their leader key for almost everything I wanted to implement something similar to my vimrc.
Specifically the " ws" as a s-split is much more comfortable then the default keybinding "ctrl-w s"

Is it possible to map "ctrl" to my leader key (which is " " space)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim won't let you map the Control key individually.

Instead, you can make custom mappings:

```
nnoremap <leader>ws <C-w>s
nnoremap <leader>wv <C-w>v
etc.
```

Comment: Btw which more ctrl-w keys should I add. I added <C-w>o

Comment: And all the movements hjkl

Comment: Add the ones you use often.